# get data from Meteor collection in client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to access collection on client-side javascript files to sort data and perform various operations. Currently I'm just using `find()` or `findOne()`, but it's very inconsistent and sometimes doesn't return value quickly enough so it doesn't work.

Am I doing it the right way? Are there any other options provided to retrieve and manipulate collection data?

For example, I want to find this data:

```
data = Stats.findOne({
  name: Session.get('name')
}, {sort: {date: -1}});
variable = data.variable;
```

And then I want to use `variable` to filter collection:

```
ranking = Stats.find({
  variable: variable
}, {sort: {score: -1}}).fetch();
```

I can't find a reason why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor is reactive, which means that as that Stats collection populates with data from the server, code that uses it will be automatically re-run.  If you're trying to display the `data` on screen, you want to use a helper, a [reactive variable](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var), and the autorun function.

JS:

```
Template.yourTemplate.onCreated( function() {
  var template = this;
  template.variable = new ReactiveVar( null );
  template.autorun( function() {
    var result = Stats.findOne({ name: Session.get('name') }, { sort: { date: -1 } });
    if( result && result.variable ) {
      template.variable.set( result.variable );
    }
  });
});

Template.yourTemplate.helpers({
  ranking() {
    return Stats.find({ variable: Template.instance().variable.get() }, { sort: { score: -1 } }).fetch();
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<template name="yourTemplate">
  {{#each rank in ranking}}
    Do stuff with {{rank}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

This will ensure that your reactive variable changes as `Stats.findOne()` of your session variable changes, and that your template can appropriately get the rankings you want.

Comment: Hi, I used your solution and it doesn't seem to work. It returns a classic `Cannot read property 'variable' of undefined` on if condition checking for variable in result. I double checked, everything is as you written. I'll work on it, but right now I didn't make any progress. EDIT: btw I installed `reactive-var` and restarted server, so this shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: You could change the `if` statement to `if( result && result.variable )`

Comment: This works! Adding `result` to the `if` statement fixed the error. Thanks a lot!